# Subscript operator and implicit conversion to a pointer type

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion, function-templates, conversion-operator

I'm reading C++ Templates - The Complete Guide, 2nd Edition, and B.2.1 tells about implicit conversion of the implied "this" argument.

Same example here:
http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2004/n1592.pdf

> Depending on the typedef of ptrdiff_t, the compiler may deduce that there is an ambiguity between
>   BadString::operator[] and converting the implied "this" argument to char * and using the built-in subscript
>   operator.

Can somebody please explain how is obj[0] expression related to this conversion and why compiler acts the way it acts in three examples below?

Thank you.

```
int main() {
    abc x;
    auto first = x[1];
    auto second = x + 2;
    return 0;
}
```

Works (why?):

```
struct abc
{
    operator bool *() { return {}; }
};
```

Doesn't work (why):

```
struct abc
{
    template <typename T>
    operator T *() = delete;
};

template <>
abc::operator int *() { return {}; }
```

Doesn't work (use of overloaded operator '[]' is ambiguous):

```
struct abc
{
    operator bool *() { return {}; }
    template <typename T>
    operator T *() = delete;
};

template <>
abc::operator int *() { return {}; }
```

Comment: "_Explicit constructors (**including copy
constructors**) were added to prevent unintended conversions being silently called by the compiler_" doesn't make much sense. The first C++ std specified that an implementation should suppress the programmer if he tried to create such beast

Comment: `= delete` doesn't remove things from the overload set.  Notice that the specialization of the template isn't changing anything, same ambiguity error from https://rextester.com/OXE95586

Comment: "_a conversion would also make the compiler uncomplainingly accept code which
was semantic nonsense:_" Assuming types A and B can both be converted to a boolean, testing if they convert to the same boolean is well defined and not "semantic nonsense". The paper OTOH spouts nonsense. `operator char* (); operator char const* ();` providing both conversions is really bizarre

Comment: `= delete` is irrelevant, the intent is not to remove this template operation from the overload set, just to make sure `int` specialization is the only one available for use.